# What is type CameraOptions in this Xamarin custom renderer tutorial?

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, camera, xamarin.forms

I am most likely just an idiot, for which I apologise in advance. Anyways, I'm trying to add camera functionality into my Xamarin.Forms (iOS-focused) app.

I found this tutorial on Xamarin's website and was following it (https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/custom-renderer/view/).

However, I don't see where the type CameraOptions is defined - it's throwing an error for me, something along the lines of "no definition for CameraOptions in this context".

I figured I must be missing a "using" statement, but I can't think of any to use.

This is part of the code where I start getting confused:

```
public class CameraPreview : View
{
  public static readonly BindableProperty CameraProperty =
    BindableProperty.Create<CameraPreview, CameraOptions> (p => p.Camera, CameraOptions.Rear);

  public CameraOptions Camera {
    get { return (CameraOptions)GetValue (CameraProperty); }
    set { SetValue (CameraProperty, value); }
  }
}
```

Seriously now. What is the CameraOptions type? It's not mentioned a single time in the whole tutorial, it's just used in the code, so I must be missing something.

Comment: CameraOptions is an enum defined in the `CameraOptions.cs` file

Comment: Didn't notice there was a full source available. See it now, thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's an enumeration defined [here](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/blob/master/CustomRenderers/View/CustomRenderer/CameraOptions.cs).  The entire source of the example is linked at the top of the page.